# Efficient way to make a multi-diagonal matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

Is there an efficient way to produce square multi-diagonal matricies such as these:

```
[[1,2,3],
 [2,1,2],
 [3,2,1]]

[[1,2,3,4,5],
 [2,1,2,3,4],
 [3,2,1,2,3],
 [4,3,2,1,2],
 [5,4,3,2,1]]
```

My efforts so far have produced the following:

```
t=10
sum=zeros(t,t)
for i=1:t
 sum+=diag(ones(1,i)*(t-i)+1,t-i);
end
sum
sum+sum'-diag(ones(1,10),0)
```

Comment: it looks like a [latin square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `toeplitz` does exactly what you want:

```
toeplitz([1,2,3,4,5,6])

ans =

 1     2     3     4     5     6
 2     1     2     3     4     5
 3     2     1     2     3     4
 4     3     2     1     2     3
 5     4     3     2     1     2
 6     5     4     3     2     1
```

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is called a symmetric (Hermitian) toeplitz matrix.

I'm not familiar with matlab, but I found [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/toeplitz.html) documentation on mathworks: